# Proof for the time complexity in big O of a inserting unique numbers in a list

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I was writing a simple loop in C++ and was wondering what the time complexity would be.

My intuition tells me that it is `O(n*log(n))` but I couldn't come up for a proof for the `n*log(n)`

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3}; 
std::vector<int> unique_nums; 
// get all unique nums
for(auto n: nums)
{
    if(std::find(unique_nums) != unique_nums.end())
    {
        unique_nums.push_back(n);
    }
}
```

This is my current understanding. `std::find` is a linear time search through the vector but the size of `unique_nums` vector is growing at an unknown rate.

Questions are:

1. Am I correct in thinking that the time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`
2. If that is true, is there a proof or formula that I could apply to see that?

Comment: why do you think it is `O(n * log(n))` ?

Comment: `std::find` is `O(n)` you have a loop over `nums` so total complexity is `O(n^2)`! Imagine input contains only unique values.

Comment: `for(auto n: nums)` is O(n); `if(std::find(unique_nums) != unique_nums.end())` is also O(n), so your algorithm is O(n^2); if you want to make it n*lon(n), use some autosortable container

Comment: Use `std::unordered_set` for `unique_nums` and you will have `O(n)`. If you know range of  values in advance then proper use of primitive `std::array` will give you fastest solution.

Comment: thanks @MarekR and pptaszni  :-) It's pretty obvious now that you pointed out the worst case. Not sure what was going on in my head :-D

Comment: A better approach would be to sort `nums` and then use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). Now you're O(n).

Comment: @PeteBecker wouldn't the sort in that case be a minimum of `O(nlog(n))` ?

Comment: @cjds --yup. O(n log(n)), not O(n). But that's still a better approach. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case is when the input has only unique numbers. In that case, the equivalent is:

```
for(auto n: nums)
{
    std::find(unique_nums);   // we already know that it is not found
                              // because input is unique numbers
    unique_nums.push_back(n); // and we have to push_back anyhow
}
```

`std::find` is linear in size of `unique_nums` and `push_back` is amortized constant. The leading term of the sum `1 + 2 + .... + n` is `n^2`, hence we can say that complexity of the loop is `O(nums.size()*nums.size())`.